# RxJava versus AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, rx-java, background-thread

Is it considered a good practice to use RxJava instead of AsyncTask in Android? For example, if I want to make a query to database, which method would be more efficient? And If an activity finishes, does a background thread die?

Comment: may be first of all you should read beautiful documentation for RxJava http://reactivex.io/

Comment: @Drake thank you, but I've read the documentation. To make it clear for everybody at home: I am asking if there is any benefit of using RxJava's Observable as an alternative for AsyncTask?

Comment: this is mostly opinion-based. It can be argued both ways.

Comment: Query *what* database? Is there an `Observable` Rx-binding for that library? If not, you are stuck writing it yourself or using AsyncTask

Comment: "And If an activity finishes, does a background thread die?" -- nope. a thread's lifecycle is not tied to that of an Activity.